# Winterfell - how to set custom validation message

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [Winterfell](https://github.com/andrewhathaway/Winterfell) library to create my forms by specifying in schema.js file. 
Winterfell provides default error messages when validation fails.
How can I override these error messages with my own custom messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winterfell's docs describe how you can [override standard and define custom error messages](https://github.com/andrewhathaway/Winterfell#custom-error-messages):

```
var Winterfell = require('winterfell');

Winterfell.addErrorMessage('isLength', 'My error message. Not long enough!');
```

Comment: Another way I found is adding custom message from schema:

'validations' : [{
        'type' : 'isRequire',
        'message' : 'Name can not be empty'
      }]